# Creating multivariate regression model out of multiple univariate models

Tags: regression, machine-learning, multivariate-analysis, univariate, conditional-independence

A bunch of ML regression models are defined only for predicting the value of a single variable.
Or have standard implementation that are only for the univariate case.
For example support vector machine and random forest regression models.

I am contemplating the naive (but generic) way to extend them for multivariate regression,
via training seperate models for each output variables.

Am I right in saying this would only be correct if the output variables are conditionally independent, when conditioning upon the input feature variables?